# How to set the reset password link in codeigniter / PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a reset password function

The idea is

add a field in the User Table e.g. `pw_reset_code varchar (40) Nullable`,

then I randomly generate a key and add it to that field when the user request to get the password.

Also, generate the get reset key link e.g.

http://myadmin.com/reset/123233432423412342342343434324234

Then, the reset php is to check whether the key e.g. 123233432423412342342343434324234 is exist in the database ,

update the password for the user that match to the key, and remove the key

So, is it the correct way to create the reset password function? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like that yes.

But you could also have it in a spererate table, which stores time, ip-adress, and id.

To add some extra security I would add the userid, or if you don't want to show it, the username, and the key.

Then have it expire in an hour or so.

Also add an field if the key is already used.

So if someone tries to retrieve an password multiple times from a user and fail.

You could notify the user that someone is probably trying to get into their account.

And btw, there's no "correct way". There's different ways to solve a problem and in the end it's up to you.

Comment: that means I need to track the request time, so that not allow user to request too many times